# Visual C++ says cannot open file '\.obj'

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, linker

This is the error I am getting- LNK1104: cannot open file '.obj' I have checked the linker and there are no spaces or missing semicolons which are cited as reasons for such error. I am using Visual Studio 2012.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IESA.jpg

Comment: The `obj` files are outputs from C/C++ compilation units, they have nothing to do with `lib` dependencies. Look at the full command lines for the compiler and linker and check the source files in the project have correct names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. There was a backward slash after a path in the linker that was causing the problem.